# Checking online status from an iPhone web app

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile-safari

Is there a way to check to see if an iPhone is online from a web app. That is, in mobile Safari, can I check the online status of the device to see if I should try an AJAX call or not.

In Firefox/regular WebKit, this would be:

```
if(navigator.onLine) 
{
    onlineCode() 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

img src="http://aonlinesite.com/a-really-little-image.png" onload="Intenet!" onerror="NoInternet!"

Comment: Not so clever considering it fails in 30% of browsers (since both attributes are not standard). Quite sad, would have been a nice solution. :(

Answer (score 3):

A quick test on the iPhone shows that it is available from iPhone OS 2.2.

Answer (score 2):

That same code should work in the WebKit nightly build as of May 16th 2008. I guess that means you need to hope the 2.1 update included a new build of safari.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=19105